# Number of ways to color n squares

Tags: algorithm

given n*1 rectangle so n square of 1*1 dimension, find in how many ways can we color the squares with red, green and blue color such that red color should be used at least r times, green color g times and blue color b times. I have searched google, wikipedia but don't know how to approach

Comment: Suppose there's some additional constraint, like 'adjacent squares' colors must differ'...?

Comment: No such constraint, actually i'm unable to figure out how to appraoch..., i have edited question actually min r tmes red color to be used...

Comment: Cant give a full answer so link only http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient i think that shoukd be a good start

Comment: Thanks Christopher Wirt, so, is this number of way of distributing n items to 3 people such that 1st one must get atleast r items, second one must get atleast b items, third one must get atleast g items. But what it will be?? and if we need to print combination then how???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you should be able to find ideas in any textbook on combinatorial mathematics, my approach would be:

There are n!/(r!*(n-r)!) combinations of *exactly* r out of n squares coloured in red and for each of these there are (n-r)!/(g!*(n-r-g)!) combinations of *exactly* g out of the remaining (n-r) squares in green; if you multiply these you get the number of colourings with r red, g green and b=n-r-g blue squares (unless you want to admit some squares remaining uncoloured, then add another factor for the number of combinations of blue squares among those not red nor green remaining).

If you want to consider different values for r and g, you need to compute the sum over all possible r and g (keep in mind that this sum will be finite due to the restraint r+g=n-b and n >= r, g, b >= 0 or whatever minimum you want).